# Python script imports wrong pandas version

Tags: python, pandas, pip, raspberry-pi

I´m running a python script on my Raspberry Pi 4 which imports pandas.
When I check the pandas version inside the script  with

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.show_versions()
```

And run the script with:

```
python3 myscript.py
```

The output is:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
python: 3.7.3.final.0
pandas: 0.23.3
numpy: 1.21.6
```

But when I use the console and check the pandas version by pip

```
pip3 list
```

The output is:

```
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
numpy              1.23.5
pandas             1.5.2
```

Why does *pip3* shows a different version then *python3* and how can I force to use the "right" version? I´m not using any virtual environments.

Side fact:
Have the same issue with pip itself. Calling it inside the script returns 18.1 and checking on conole returns 22.3.1

Comment: Using `pip(3) debug | grep executable` shows which Python version corresponds to pip. Probably you got multiple Python versions installed ... create and use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer by default there is python 2.7 and 3.7 installed on Raspi. If I check pip2 there is no pandas installed. So the pandas 1.5.2 must be somewhere else.

Comment: echo a vritual env especially if you don't know how to reconcile your various python versions.

Comment: You could run `python3 -m pip list` and see how that compares to `pip3 list`. Also `which python3` and `which pip3` would be interesting. Finally look at the fist line of `pip3`. Its likely a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python3`. If that shebang is different than the python you got with `witch`. there's your problem.

Comment: `pip` isn't that good at dealing with mulitple pythons. Virtual environments write their own stub pip to help with the problem. Or Generally, use `python3 -m pip ...` instead. That ensures that the current python is the one you'll use.

Comment: Important reading: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
import pandas as pd 
print(pd.__version__)
```

Can you please try the below method?

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("pandas==1.5.2")
import pandas as pd 
print(pd.__version__)
```

pkgs are installed, we can use the above method to get to the desired version.

> Since I do not have enough reputation, I am unable to keep comments :(